# Install arm64 packages on A amd64 machine

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, ubuntu-20.04

I have A Raspberry Pi 3 device, the arch is arm64. And I have a ubuntu computer, the arch is amd64. I am doing the cross compile. I want to do the cross compile my code on the ubuntu and then copy the executables to the Raspberry to execute. My software depends opencv, ffmpeg...etc. I Have tried the MultiArch solution. When I try to download ffmpeg:arm64, the apt show me this error.
[image: this Picture]

So I tried to download the first dependency libavcodec58, but the result is:
[image: this picture]

and When I tried to install the dependency glibc, the result is here:
[image: this picture]

The Apt will remove all the libraries from my current system.
So could anyone can help me about this?

Comment: You need a ARM toolchain installed on your AMD64 machine. That will make cross-compiling a bit convenient I guess.

Comment: @kiner_shah I already have Installed the aarch64 toolchain on my AMD64 machine，but build the ffmpeg and the dependency libraries maybe impossiable, there are too many libraries to build. So I expect to install the pre-built libraries.

Comment: ***maybe impossible, there are too many libraries to build*** This is just a one time effort. Once built, you probably won't be changing any library source code, so it will take much less time for subsequent changes in your project code.